# regex - search for pattern that starts with alphabetics and ends with alphabets or space

Tags: regex, character-properties

What is the correct regex for getting a string that contains only letters, must start with letters and a continuous string of letters.  But can end with letters OR a space (just space and not tabs or returns).

I have this pattern `/^\S*[a-zA-Z]\s*$/`

Is it correct?  do I need the `\S*` at the start and how do I ensure that there is no spaces in between letters?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it must start with letters, contain only letters (no spaces), and could end with a *single* space i think it should be

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ ?$
```

Comment: Thanks jambriz, this works too.  My problem now is to investigate which solution is most optimal for getting about 90K matches out of a 200K array.

Answer (score 2):

`/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]$/`

No need for `\S*`

And you can test it online. There are websites such as http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/ to check regex.

Comment: That site looks pretty good. Try http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. It's my regex weapon of choice :). I really like the real-time updating and the replace option.

Comment: Thanks RNAer, that testing website looks good.  It actually is intuitive and I can test my string a see the outputs.  Also, I modified your regex to take out the 'space' that comes after the + sign.  That mod works for my intent. /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]$/

Comment: @Jamex:Yes. That space is a typo. It should be removed. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

`^[a-zA-Z]+?[a-zA-Z ]$`

This assumes a modern regular expression processor which allows for non-greedy (`+?`) repeats.

Comment: Thanks Lance, this works for my purpose.  But for my purpose, it can also work without the '?' mark.  ^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]$

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible:

```
^\pL ?$
```

Comment: Thanks M42 for your time, I am sure this is really useful if I know which context to apply it to.